# move up the files from subdirectory in root directory

Tags: python, file, directory

I have the following folder hierarchy:

```
----Folder
------Subfolders
-----------Sub-sub-folder
--------------Files
```

So I have multiple subfolders, and in every Subfolder I have one Sub-sub-folder that contains multiple files, that I want to move up from Sub-sub-folder to Subfolder

The easiest, and dirty way of doing this: just copy files from sub-sub-folder to Subfolder and then delete the sub-sub-folder. 
But if you know better pythonic way of doing this, please let me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil

Subfolders = os.listdir('Folder')            # get the list of Subfolders
for Subfolder in Subfolders:                 # iterate thru each subfolder
    sfiles = os.listdir('Folder/Subfolder/Sub-sub-folder') # get list of file at each Subfolder/Sub-sub-folder
        for sfile in sfiles:
            shutil.move(sfile, Subfolder) # each file in subfolder is moved to subfolder
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import os
import shutil

path = 'Folder'                                                    #set target folder

Subfolders = os.listdir(path)                                      #get list of subfolders 

for Subfolder in Subfolders:                                       #for each listed subfolder
    Subsubfolders = os.listdir(path+'/'+Subfolder)                 #get list of sub-subfolders
    for Subsubfolder in Subsubfolders:                             #and cycle through them
        sfiles = os.listdir(path+'/'+Subfolder + '/' Subsubfolder) #to get list of files in every sub-subfolder
        for sfile in sfiles:                                       #and move every listed file
            shutil.move(path+'/'+Subfolder+'/'+'/'+ Subsubfolder+'/'+sfile, path)
```